# How to authenticate current user with Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I want to authenticate the current user using Active Directory, I don't want to use user password. If a user logged in the system then it should check for active directory whether the user is valid or not. I have got lots of code but they are using password..

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a similar question:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31866/active-directory-auto-login-to-website-for-domain-users

Also this article which guides you to the steps to achieve the same : 
[How to implement Windows authentication and authorization in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323176)

Both the above examples do not use any password to login.

If your Internet Explorer still asks you for login details then it can be because of your IE settings:

In Internet Explorer go to Tools -> Internet Option -> Security -> Custom Level -> Scroll down to  the bottom and select "Automatic Login with current user name and password” -> OK -> OK -> Close and reopen browser.

This should allow an AD authenticated user to pass straight through to your page.